# Run custom jquery file in bootstrap but failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I had wrote a jquery script with GoogleMap API and worked when I putted it in blank HTML page, like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
  //my script here...
</scripn>
</head>
<body>
<section id="about" class="container content-section text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <div id="map-canvas"></div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
//it works fine.
</body>
</html>
```

and now I'm trying to pack the jquery script into a js file, and include it into bootstrap, but the work failed.
I had looked for some solution here but all did not work for me.
1. [Custom jQuery Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740051/custom-jquery-functions)
2. [Bootstrap Custom jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26871614/bootstrap-custom-jquery)
3. [Run js script anyway at initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626584/run-js-script-anyway-at-initialization)
4. [Bootstrap modal opening on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28068119/bootstrap-modal-opening-on-page-load)
I was using this Bootstrap [template](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/grayscale/). please help me for this, thanks.

#### JS file were included in `<footer>` tag

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>    
<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<!-- Google Maps API Key - Use your own API key to enable the map feature. More information on the Google Maps API can be found at https://developers.google.com/maps/ -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCRngKslUGJTlibkQ3FkfTxj3Xss1UlZDA&sensor=false"></script>
<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="js/grayscale.js"></script>
<!-- drink Map JavaScript -->
<script src="js/drinkmap.js"></script>
```

#### jquery script were wrapped like this

```
$(function() {
  var x = [];
  var list = [];
  var map;
  for(var s = 0; s < jsfile.length; s++) {
    $.getJSON(jsfile[s], function(json) {
      for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        x.push({
        //push some info like name, latlng
        });
      }
    });  
  }
  //start navigator
  function getUserGeolocation() {
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(parsePosition, noGeolocation);
    } else { handleNoGeolocation(false); }
  }
  //success callback of getCurrentPosition and do map work
  function parsePosition(pos) { ... }
  //error callback of geolocation.getCurrentPosition
  function noGeolocation() { handleNoGeolocation(true); }
  function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) { ... }
});
```

either I got error like this in firefox debug

```
SyntaxError: illegal character
}
```

or I could not show the map in the `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

for someone also looking the answer with similar question like me,
finally I found that it was sort of Vagrant/VirtualBox Nginx cache behavior problem...
the issue and solution is here for reference: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/351

I get into `nginx.conf` located at `/etc/nginx/` and change `sendfile on;` to `sendfile off;`, then restart nginx and everything works.